# How to find row with highest value based on another column

Tags: mysql

There are multiple lineitem ids and I want to return the row with the largest quantity for each lineitem id. What is the best way to do this in Mysql?

```
Row completed_at    lineitem_id quantity
1   2020-03-12  4453468635184   1
2   2020-03-06  4453468635184   2
3   2020-03-17  4480921108528   4
4   2020-03-25  4480921108528   2
5   2020-03-25  4481446608944   3
6   2020-03-17  4481446608944   5
```

Comment: If you show us some ways, we can identify which is best. Failing that, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

With mysql you can write like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM your_table
   ORDER BY lineitem_id, quantity DESC
   LIMIT 9999999999999 -- for mariadb, support order in subquery
) AS your_alias
GROUP BY lineitem_id
```